# What is this symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to find out what the below symbol is (does it have a name? What does it represent?) and also, does Unicode have a codepoint for it? For what it's worth, the image is a binarized screenshot from a PDF.

[image: star-or-wheel-like-symbol]

My first attempt was to try and draw it in [shapecatcher](https://shapecatcher.com/), and then, realizing I'm terrible at drawing things, even moreso with a mouse, I tried searching for similar websites that will allow uploading an image. The only thing I found was "[drewish Image to Unicode](https://drewish.com/projects/unicoder/)" which doesn't find anything. Next I tried Google Image Search, which interestingly came up with [the English Wikipedia's article on Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language), but skimming over that, nothing helpful stood out.

Does anybody know what symbol this is, and whether it has a representation in Unicode?

Also, since this is my first post to the Graphic Design community, please do let me know in the comments if I can improve this question in any way!

Comment: I don't think it is a character/symbol, at least not one I recognize.  Why don't you just try to recreate it using a vector image editor? You could auto trace it.

Comment: I'm guessing there's not a unicode symbol for whatever this is. I recommend using a vector editor to recreate it. Doing so shouldn't take that much time, even for a person new to vector editors. I'd probably create one of the blobs then repeat it 7 more times, rotating each instance. The closest unicode is probably [Rub el Hizb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub_el_Hizb) or an 8 pointed star.

Comment: I am not trying to make this pretty, I need to know what it is, to be able to OCR the text from the PDF properly. To that effect, creating it as a vector image doesn't help.

Comment: If it has some connection with Indian/Hindu culture, I suppose you could call it a [Star of Lakshmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_Lakshmi). It also says Sanskrit: अष्टलक्ष्मी, Aṣṭalakṣmi, lit. Eightfold Lakshmi

Comment: In English - the word "octagram" is also used for similar designs.